# IP packets get queued in intermediate routers and can delay their delivery to the destination?

Tags: ip, tcp

TCP segment go inside IP packets,there are many problems

IP packets get queued in intermediate routers and can delay their delivery to the destination?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TCP segment go inside IP packets,there are many problems

I really do not understand that statement. Yes, transport protocols, like TCP, are the payload of network protocols, like IP, but that is how it is designed, not a problem.

> IP packets get queued in intermediate routers and can delay their
>   delivery to the destination?

Yes, it is possible that packets get queued when there is network congestion. Queuing can cause delay, but the alternative is to simply drop excess packets in congestion, and that can be worse than delay.

Comment: that queue is buffering ?

Comment: Technically queuing and buffering are the same thing, but network queuing is not like buffering a video on your PC. Network queues are relatively small. Network queuing is a very large subject and part of QoS that is a huge subject.

Comment: got it,it's helpful for me